# 3DTouch Probing Off the Bed X-axis

Tags: creality-ender-3, 3dtouch

I have an Ender 3 V2 and a 3DTouch Makerbase sensor.

I have a problem with the bed leveling test.

The first test points are good, after that the nozzle try to test on the X axis outside the bed as can be seen [in this video](https://files.fm/u/qjde6eg7z).

I hope you can help me

Comment: The problem is that the X-axis doesn't move back after the first 4 probes. This must be a 3DTouch not a BLTouch. What firmware are you using, or what did you change in the configuration files?

Comment: I tried several firmware, and I have the same problem. Marlin-bugfix-2.0.x and I followed the steps of Teaching Tech - Ender 3 V2, BLtouch & more, Smith3D-E3V2-2.0.x.14-5x5-SlowProbe, Marlin-bugfix-2.0.x and I followed Makerbase 3D Touch V2.0 Tutorial

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP. I notice that the video is stored on Whatsapp, and I wonder if they have a pre-determined life expectancy. That is to say, will the video be purged after a certain timeframe? If so, then your question may become a little unclear after that time period is up. If that is the case then it might be better to move the video to YouTube.